# Dot product between two 5D matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to do the dot product between two 3x3x3x3x3 matrices in Matlab.
Following the Matlab documentation about the [dot](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html#bt9p_hk-1) function for multidimensional arrays, I expect the result of this:

```
A=2*ones(3,3,3,3,3);

B=3*ones(3,3,3,3,3);

dot(A,B,1);
```

to be a 4D matrix, because the dot product between each column of A and each column of B reduces the resulting matrix by a dimension.
Instead, this is the output in the workspace:

[image: workspace]

I can't understand this, why does it happen?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is a 5-D double because you've collapsed the first dimension. So the first dimension is now of size `1`, and the 2nd-5th dimensions are of size `3` as expected.

You can see this by using `size`

```
A = 2 * ones(3,3,3,3,3);
B = 3 * ones(3,3,3,3,3);

C = dot(A,B,1);

size( C ); % = [1 3 3 3 3]
```